# Crash when push to webView on iOS 17

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, ios17

After updating iOS 17, pushing from the controller in webview stopped working for me, and it throws the following error when pushing: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16f497ff0)! Anyone who has encountered a similar problem, help me!

Comment: Any error message in console?